# I have an error "incompatible type" with the PreparedStatement

Tags: java

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
public class preparedstatementdemo
    {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception
        {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:yoksource","","");
        String Sqlcmd="insert into yokrecord values(?,?,?)";
    **    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(Sqlcmd);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter a name");
        ps.setString(1,br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter age");
        ps.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
        System.out.println("enter address");
        ps.setString(3,br.readLine());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("inserted");
        }
    }
```

** error :incompatible type

Comment: Elaborate your question in the question body.

Comment: Please pricese where the error occurs and give us more details :)

Comment: On which line do you get error? stack trace of error?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide both, inputs and table definition.

Comment: I think this is clear. The values u are setting are not expected by the input. Example if the 1st param is expected int u are sending String.

Comment: String values in statements must be surrounded with single quotes: "insert into yokrecord values('string_value',?,?)"

Comment: @Max but br.readLine() anway returns string, so that should not be the issue. in setInt(), the OP is converting it to int.

Comment: -1 for not being able to formulate a clear question with concrete error message.

Comment: i am sorry .i don,t know where to write a question  the error in the line with ** . when in compile it says "incompatible type with the line ** .

Comment: @yok - there's nothing wrong with the code as you pasted it.  is that the actual code you are compiling?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with the actual `INSERT` command you use -- the syntax shold be:

```
INSERT INTO yokrecord (fieldname1,fieldname2,fieldname3) values(?,?,?);
```

Comment: I try what u say but still got the same error                                     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types
  required: PreparedStatement
  found:    java.sql.PreparedStatement
        at preparedstatementdemo.main(preparedstatementdemo.java:10)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)

Comment: does your datasource specifies a database where you have a table called yokrecord?